# Sometimes gdal.RasterizeLayer makes geometry invisible

Tags: gdal, rasterization

Honestly I don't know how to explain what's going on correctly but I'll try.
I have a table in `postgres` that I trying to rasterize, and I want to make a separate raster for every feature.
Everything works, but sometimes I get `tif images` that look like this:
[image]

So it's completely black and min and max values = 0. But if I change max value to `1` feature will appears:
[image]

This effect not a random. It always happens with this feature when I trying to make image where this feature in corner. If I make image where it feature in center everything fine.
Here is my code:

```
inp_lyr = outLayer #layer that contains only one feature
inp_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
inp_srs.ImportFromProj4('my_srs')

x_ncells = 1024
y_ncells = 1024

# Output
out_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
out_source = out_driver.Create(output_tiff, x_ncells, y_ncells, 1, gdal.GDT_Int32)
out_source.SetGeoTransform((x_min, cellsize, 0, y_max, 0, -cellsize))
out_source.SetProjection(inp_srs.ExportToWkt())
gdal.RasterizeLayer(out_source, [1], inp_lyr, burn_values = [1], options =['ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE'] )

# Save and/or close the data sources
out_source.FlushCache()
out_source = None
```

What should I check here?